# phonegap/cordova PayPal intergration

Tags: php, javascript, cordova, paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal payments within my Phonegap app. I can't see a cross platform way to do it.

I can only see OS specific plugins which I can't use in Phonegap build. Is there a way of integrating it using the childbrowser? Also, I failed to find a plugin for Blackberry.

Note: I use Phonegap build, so I prefer a plugin-less solution.

Comment: Referring to https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins, there isn't Paypal in the plugin list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you can do is the in app browser to connect to a php driven page online and there do your paypal stuff.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
}
```

Remember to white list the url that you will be using within phonegap else you will not to be able to make a connection.

On the php side write your own restfull api to handle the processing of the payments try to minimize the data sent to and from the api also try to use a secure connection if possible.

paypal examples can be found here:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples

its a solution but i do advise to use plugins for every platform, with those you can better guarantee safety, less bugs and less development time.